# How to validate number array in nestjs?

Tags: nestjs

````
```@IsNumber()
@ValidateNested({ each: true })
users: number[];```
````

I am trying to pass a number array like so [1000,10002] to an enpoint in my app and cannot seem to achieve the desired result with the validation. Any ideas? This produces an error like this -
value in nested property users must be either object or array

Comment: Why are you using `@ValidateNested()`? Why not something like `@IsArray()`?

Comment: tryed it aswell. same mistake. forgot to mention

Comment: @IsNumber({}, {each: true}) This helped. Couldnt find the docs but i tryed it and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comments, you have to use `@IsNumber(numberValdiatorOptions, { each: true })` [which is briefly mentioned at high level here](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#validating-arrays).

[You can view this stackblitz with a working configuration](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-myazn7?file=index.ts)